# JavaScript Gantt editor with collapsible tasks as open-source?

Tags: javascript, extjs, open-source, project-management, gantt-chart

Does somebody know about a Gantt chart with *collapsible* tasks? There are a number of charts around with a plain list of tasks, but I believe that the [+]/[-] option is necessary in order to deal with medium-sized projects. Bryntum.com has developed one for Sencha Ext-JS, but we would be looking for an open-source version.

Answer (score 2):

If open source GPL license works for you, you can try dhtmlxGantt. It's a customizable JavaScript Gantt chart with collapsible tasks: http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml

(Disclaimer: I work for DHTMLX)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make Gantt Charts with collapsible tasks, but you have to play around allot with the tools in SSRS. For example you could make a Tablix with rowgroups like Projektnames and Parent rowgroups like Names of the coworkers or something like this. Remove the detail rows and add a Rectangle instead. Here you can put your Gantt-Chart (Range-Chart or whatever). 
After all you can change the Groupvisiblity Settings so it fits all your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://roberto.open-lab.com/2014/05/15/jquery-gantt-editor-collapsible-branches/
is by far the best open source solution (MIT). Smooth SVG drawing and print friendly

Answer (score 0):

Just to comment on my own question: We (the http://www.project-open.com/ team) have decided to build our own Gantt Editor using Sencha Ext-JS, because none of the existing solutions really satisfies our needs. The resulting code will be available under GPL V3 plus a proprietary license. An alpha version should be ready towards spring 2014.

Comment: The first documentation of the new package is available at: http://www.project-open.org/en/package_sencha_gantt_editor